# Sphinx & PHP : How to minimize repetition

Tags: php, random, sphinx

I have a service using sphinx version 0.9.9-release (r2117) (I know.. I know.. it's super old, but to update sphinx is not an option at all).

Sphinx settings:

limit 1000000

offset 0

index main+delta

Basically it's a profile table. First I have to sort profiles by gender and age. Than I need to add some randomization to fetch variety of profiles out of these sorted.

The sort expression I currently have is pretty complex:

```
$sortExpression .= " + (" . bindec('10000000000000000') . " * (gender <> 0))";
$sortExpression .= " + ((age > 0) * (" . bindec('111111100000000') . " - ABS(age - " . $this->mProfileInfo['age'] . ")))";
...
// Random.
$randomMod = floor(mt_rand(0, 385));
$sortExpression .= " + ((idprofile - (FLOOR(idprofile / " . $randomMod . ") * " . $randomMod . ")) * 0.01)";
```

Also I need to call sphinx search several times and collect results of all these calls. The problem is that out of a hundred available profiles there is always repetition in result set (result of several sphinx calls).

How can I reduce the repetitions in the sphinx search results on the sorted data?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "(result of several sphinx calls)."? Why are you calling multiple times? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @barryhunter, thank you for trying to help! I've already lost hope anybody would answer my question. It's not easy to explain details, and I'm a noob in sphinx in general.   The logic is to find matches for a profile by age and gender. There is a range of age set. The point is that for several profiles the same matching profile is selected - no matter that I have hundreds of profile within the same age range. I need to add some randomization there.

Comment: You mean you see the some profiles 'appear' in random results, more often than others? Is so its because you using a bad 'random sorting' method. Your current system, is very biased, documents with a prime id, will show are very differently to a easily divisible number (I dont know if less or more, as it depends on the rest of the expression and sort order). You need a better random system. Hard to recommend one without knowing more

Answer (score 0):

Attention: legacy code issue! Update sphinx version was not an option.

It's been a while since I posted this question, the task for sphinx randomization issue was in progress in parallel with other duties. Basically the solution is a combination of several actions. Here are what actually helped in the end:

- we decided to rid of sphinx randomization so this part of code was removed forever:

  // Random.
  $randomMod = floor(mt_rand(0, 385));
  $sortExpression .= " + ((idprofile - (FLOOR(idprofile / " . $randomMod . ") * " . $randomMod . ")) * 0.01)";

  As a result, sphinx results became more predictable.
- instead of sphinx randomization, php randomization was added. So we shuffled all equal profiles (insuring that the amount of equal profiles is reasonable) before fetching few of them
- removed any sphinx sorting based on datetime field. Even transferred to months since last activity it used to give unwanted results.

  As a result, amount of shuffled profiles is significantly increased
- removed from sphinx unnecessary fields

If somebody ever meet a challenge similar to what we impacted, I hope this experience would be useful in any behalf.